# How to align colons on titlepage

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I would like to align the two colons in the \author field of my titlepage. Is there a possibility to do this in a similar way as in the \align environment?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{Title}
\author{Me\\Referentin: XXX \\Korreferent: XXX}
\date{9. Dezember 2013}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Bilder/titelbild/Istanbul.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{titlepage}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An up-front comment: you're on your way toward moderately abusing the spirit of LaTeX's `\author` command. This macro is designed so that the names of multiple authors are separated by `\and` instructions; the `\\` line break instruction is supposed to be used solely as a divider between an author's name and his/her affiliation (or similar such author-related information).

Anyway, to achieve your objective, all you have to do is provide a `tabular` environment inside the argument of the `\author` instruction. Just don't use any `\and` instructions...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{Title}
\author{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
  Me\\ 
  Referentin:& XXX \\ 
  Korreferent:& YYY
 \end{tabular}}
\date{9. Dezember 2013}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Remark: If you don't want your name to be (right-)aligned with the colons in lines two and three of the author block, you could insert `\phantom{:}` immediately after your name. Or, if you prefer to center your name in the left-hand column of the `tabular` environment, you'd write `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Me}` instead of just `Me`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply - this is exactly what I needed. Also thanks for the advice with the \and - now I'll know it for my future latex-documents.